# How can we riffle shuffle the elements of a list in Python?

Tags: python, riffle-shuffle

I want to shuffle the elements of a list without importing any module.
The type of shuffle is a riffle shuffle. It is where you want to divide the number of elements of the list into two and then interleave them.

If there are odd number of elements then the second half should contain the extra element.

eg:

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Then the final list should look like

```
[1,4,2,5,3,6,7]
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for fun, a recursive solution:

```
def interleave(lst1, lst2):
    if not lst1:
        return lst2
    elif not lst2:
        return lst1
    return lst1[0:1] + interleave(lst2, lst1[1:])
```

Use it as follows in Python 2.x (In Python 3.x, use `//` instead of `/`):

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
interleave(lst[:len(lst)/2], lst[len(lst)/2:])
=> [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7]
```

The above will work fine with lists of any length, it doesn't matter if the length is even or odd.

Answer (score 3):

```
listA = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
listLen = len(listA)/2
listB = listA[:listLen]
listC = listA[listLen:]
listD = []
num = 0
while num < listLen:
    if len(listB) >= num:
        listD.append(listB[num])
        listD.append(listC[num])
    num += 1
if len(listA)%2 != 0:
    listD.append(listC[num])
print listD
```

After looking at another answer, I also am adding a recursive version, which is a revised version of the other guy's answer, but easier to call as you only have to call the function with a single argument (The list you are trying to have shuffled) and it does everything else:

```
def interleave(lst):
    def interleaveHelper(lst1,lst2):
        if not lst1:
            return lst2
        elif not lst2:
            return lst1
        return lst1[0:1] + interleaveHelper(lst2, lst1[1:])
    return interleaveHelper(lst[:len(lst)/2], lst[len(lst)/2:])
```

When you go to call it, you can say `interleave(list)`

Answer (score 2):

> eg: list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>   then the final list should look like [1,4,2,5,3,6,7]

Here's a function that should do this reliably:

```
def riffle(deck):
    '''
    Shuffle a list like a deck of cards.
    i.e. given a list, split with second set have the extra if len is odd
    and then interleave, second deck's first item after first deck's first item
    and so on. Thus:
    riffle([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
    returns [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7]
    '''
    cut = len(deck) // 2                        # floor division
    deck, second_deck = deck[:cut], deck[cut:]
    for index, item in enumerate(second_deck):
        insert_index = index*2 + 1
        deck.insert(insert_index, item)
    return deck
```

and to unit-test it...

```
import unittest
class RiffleTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_riffle(self):
        self.assertEqual(riffle(['a','b','c','d','e']), ['a','c','b','d','e'])
        self.assertEqual(riffle([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]), [1,4,2,5,3,6,7])

unittest.main()
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this fairly easily with by utilizing the `next` feature of an iterator in Python.

First thing you'll want to do is split the elements into two parts.

Next, turn those two parts into iterators using Python's `iter` function. You could skip this step, but I find calling `next(iterable)` to be a lot cleaner than manually indexing a list.

Finally, you'll loop through the first half of your list, and for each element you add of that half, add the corresponding element of the latter (calling `next` gives the next item in the sequence).

For example:

```
elements = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

half_point = len(elements)/2

a = iter(elements[0:half_point])
b = iter(elements[half_point: ])

result = []
for i in range(half_point):
    result.append(next(a))
    result.append(next(b))

if len(elements) % 2 != 0:
    result.append(next(b))

print result

>>> [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7]
```

The last bit at the bottom checks to see if the list is odd. If it is, that it appends the final element onto the end of the list.

If you get creative, you could probably condense this down a good bit by zipping and then unpacking, but I'll leave that for when you explore `itertools` ;)

Comment: Instead of testing if the len of elements is even or odd, just do `result += list(b)`. If the list is of even length, then `list(b)` will be just the empty list, otherwise it will be a single length list containing the last element of the original list.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire +1 That is clever!

Answer (score 1):

You can split the input list into two parts, then use zip and some list manipulation to interleave the items.

```
n = 9
l = range(1,n+1)
a = l[:n/2]
b = l[n/2:]
c = zip(a,b)
d = list()
for p in c :
    d.extend(list(p))
if n%2==1:
    d.append(b[n/2])
print(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def riffle(deck):
    new_deck = []
    deck_1 = deck[:len(deck)//2]
    deck_2 = deck[len(deck)//2::]
    for i in range(len(deck)//2):
        new_deck.append(deck_1[i])
        new_deck.append(deck_2[i])
    if len(deck) % 2 == 1:
        new_deck.append(deck[-1])
    return new_deck


deck = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
print(riffle(deck))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find the expression `i%2`, which evaluates to 0 on even numbers and 1 on odd numbers, to alternatively access the beginning and middle of the deck.

```
def riffle(deck: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    result = []
    mid = len(deck) // 2
    for i in range(len(deck)):
        result.append(deck[i // 2 + (i % 2) * mid])
    return result
```

Or you can utilize an if expression for the odd and even numbers respectively:

```
def riffle(deck: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    result = []
    mid = len(deck) // 2
    for i in range(len(deck)):
        if not i % 2:
            result.append(deck[i // 2])
        else:
            result.append(deck[i // 2 + mid])
    return result
```

Comment: Your first method doesn't work on odd numbered lists: the last item is the middle element, rather than the last element. `return result[:-1]+deck[-1:]` instead seems to work fine for both. I imagine there might also be a more elegant way of fixing the issue.

Comment: In fact, both solutions fail for odd numbered lists, and the same solution works for both.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> ll = list(range(1,8))
>>> mid = len(ll)/2   # for Python3, use '//' operator
>>> it1 = iter(ll[:mid])
>>> it2 = iter(ll[mid:])
>>> riff = sum(zip(it1,it2), ()) + tuple(it2)
>>> riff
(1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7)
```

If this is homework, be prepared to explain how `sum` and `zip` working here, what the second parameter to `sum` is for, why `tuple(it2)` is being added to the end, and how this solution has an  inherent inefficiency.

Answer (score 0):

If deck is a list, write a function that does list comprehension to perform the shuffling:

```
def riffle_shuffle(deck):
    return [deck[i//2 + (i%2)*(len(deck)//2)] for i in range(len(deck))]
```

Comment: This doesn't work for odd numbered lists. The last element is the middle element of the input rather than the last element.