# Can someone elaborate or explain what a riffle shuffle is?

Tags: python, python-3.x, riffle-shuffle

I have to make a program in Python that shuffles cards, and makes all shuffles be perfect riffle shuffles.

This is done by taking the top half of the deck and alternating it with the bottom half of the deck. The riffle shuffle will be performed such that the new top card will come from the bottom half of the deck. Note that, the output is the top 13 cards after shuffling.

I also have two lists

```
value = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']

suits = ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S']
```

With this, can anyone give their take on how to solve this? Tips and maybe how do you understand this problem would greatly help!

I haven't tried anything yet. I stuck on understanding the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can we riffle shuffle the elements of a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19898138/how-can-we-riffle-shuffle-the-elements-of-a-list-in-python)

Comment: While you didn't mention a list, a deck of cards would most likely be implemented as a list of objects, possibly instances of a Card class. So, start with a list of simple numbers, then apply it to a list of cards.

Comment: @GinoMempin it helps a bit. But I will still leave this question unanswered as I'm very open for other people's insight regarding my problem. Thanks

Comment: @GinoMempin I edited my question and placed my list

Comment: Please share what did try so far and ask a particular question. The question "what a riffle shuffle is?" is answered in the post linked by @GinoMempin.

Comment: The point of closing and linking questions together is so that all the answers _are in one place_. The fact that your list is a list of strings is irrelevant to the algorithm, so doesn't need to be a separate question. It's better if all possible implementations are all in one place.